# Setting Zebra Printer Installation To Vertical

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

Im printing receipts to a Zebra 2030 printer and need to it to vertical printing. 
Im using the rawprinterhelper class from Microsoft to print, but my question is, how would I send the, U1 setvar "device.orientation" "value" , command to the printer.

Thanks is advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

The TTP 2030 is not a ZPL or CPCL printer and doesn't have U1 commands. If you want to print text in vertical you can use ESC o n1 with n1=0 portrait, n1=1 landscape.
You may  be better off using the Windows driver and creating a bitmap of your receipt and print this to the printer instead of relying on the text capabilities of this printer.

Comment: I did this in the end, when I had no hair left. Thanks :)

Comment: @Manfred Wilner, how did you get the TTP 2030 to print bmp. I've been working at it for day, reading the docs, and trying test files.

Comment: @sjt003 How big is your bitmap? The horizontal resolution should not be bigger rather slightly smaller than the 639 pixel of the printers resolution. The printer has a width of 80 mm with a printable area of 72 mm and 203 DPI horizontally.
If your bitmap is too big it will not print.

Comment: @ManfredWilner, the bitmap is not too big. It prints the bmp file's contents as text rather than image. What command code do you use? This code is followed by sending data directly to printer, yes?

Comment: @sjt003 The command is:
ESC b n1...n5 data Print Bitmap at XY position
B&W 1 bit color depth Windows bitmap uncompressed data starts with BM, max bitmap size can't be greater than free RAM
n1 always 0
n2n3 two byte X position
n4n5 two byte Y position
data bitmap data

Comment: @ManfredWilner I was able to get partial cut to work on a 2030 under cups by modifying your zebra cups filter (thank you btw for that), but I still am having trouble understanding the docs, and your explanation (which is the same as the docs). Am I to send the bitmap byte by byte to the printer? I have a char array of {0x1B, 0x62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, <chars of bmp file starting with BM>} which I then write to printer . I have tried writing the control codes first followed by the bitmap but this does not seem to work either. Prints the bmp chars ins ascii instead of image. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @sjt003 Would you mind sharing the bitmap so I can try it myself?